# Remove borders of a n-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to replace all the values of the border of my n-dimensional array by `False`. So far, I have seen that numpy provides `np.pad` that allows me to grow an array in all dimensions with an arbitrary array. Is there an equivalent to do the opposite and "shrink" the array by cutting the borders?

Here is an example in 2D that I would like to extend to arbitrary dimension:

```
import numpy as np

nd_array = np.random.randn(100,100)>0   # Just to have a random bool array, but the same would apply with floats, for example

cut_array = nd_array[1:-1, 1:-1]   # This is what I would like to generalize to arbitrary dimension

padded_array = np.pad(cut_array, pad_width=1, mode='constant', constant_values=False)
```

Of course, if there is an easier way to change the values of the borders in arbitrary dimension, that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use the approach of first cropping then padding, because like this you move a lot of memory around.

Instead I would explicitly set the border indexes to the desired value:

```py
import numpy as np

border_value = False
nd_array = np.random.randn(100,100) > 0

# Iterate over all dimensions of `nd_array`
for dim in range(nd_array.ndim):
    # Make current dimension the first dimension
    array_moved = np.moveaxis(nd_array, dim, 0)
    # Set border values in the current dimension
    array_moved[0] = border_value
    array_moved[-1] = border_value
    # We do not even need to move the current dimension
    # back to its original position, as `np.moveaxis()`
    # provides a view into the original data, thus by
    # altering the values of `array_moved`, we also
    # alter the values of `nd_array`. So we are done.
```

Note that `np.moveaxis()` is a pretty cheap operation, as it only adjusts the strides of the array (to produce `array_moved`, in our case), so no actual array data gets moved around.

Comment: I did not know about `np.moveaxis`, that sounds very useful. I will keep it in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note: I think [simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75987828/5256150) is better for this specific question, but I leave a method to actually remove the borders instead of replacing them, in case someone needs it.

---

[The answer by TheOneMusic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75987707/5256150) proposes a good idea by using `np.delete`, but the implementation in that answer does not provide the desided answer for any dimension. We can however use the idea by creating a recursive function that deletes the last and first elements in a given axis and all axis before it:

```
import numpy as np

def remove_borders(array, last_axis=None):
    if last_axis is None:
        last_axis = len(array.shape)
    new_array = np.delete(array, [0,-1], axis=last_axis)
    if last_axis>0:
        new_array = remove_borders(new_array, last_axis-1)
    return new_array
```

And then the rest of the script would look something like:

```
nd_array = np.random.randn(100,100) > 0   # Just to have a random bool array, but the same would apply with floats, for example

cut_array = remove_borders(nd_array)   

padded_array = np.pad(cut_array, pad_width=1, mode='constant', constant_values=False)
```

This seems to work for arbitrary dimension, although it is not optimized and it will probably struggle with big arrays of high dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to delete the last column (index 99 in your example).

```py
import numpy as np

nd_array = np.random.randn(100, 100) > 0

cut_array = np.delete(nd_array, 99, 1) # Delete 100th column (index 99)

padded_array = np.pad(cut_array, pad_width=1, mode='constant', constant_values=False)
```